# Deriving Eq and Show for an ADT that contains fields that can't have Eq or Show

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

I'd like to be able to derive `Eq` and `Show` for an ADT that contains multiple fields. One of them is a function field. When doing `Show`, I'd like it to display something bogus, like e.g. `"<function>"`; when doing `Eq`, I'd like it to ignore that field. How can I best do this without hand-writing a full instance for `Show` and `Eq`?

I don't want to wrap the function field inside a `newtype` and write my own `Eq` and `Show` for that - it would be too bothersome to use like that.

Comment: Well... _don't do this_. If the type contains a function, it _can't_ be shown or equality-compared, pretending otherwise will just lead to confusing suprises.

Comment: @leftaroundabout that's a matter of personal preference for my own codebase. Especially Show isn't going to lead to any surprises, it's only for the programmer's use during an interactive session. It's not for serialization.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you want to play by your own rules you'll need to write your own instance too. Don't expect community/libraries/tools to help you with something the community considers a bad idea...

Comment: @leftaroundabout sorry, the narrative of objectively bad and good ideas, or that your tastes represent the whole of the community, or that the community should decide what's good for me, it all goes way too far for me. That's overstepping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically what I do in this circumstance is exactly what you say you *don’t* want to do, namely, wrap the function in a `newtype` and provide a `Show` for that:

```
data T1
  { f :: X -> Y
  , xs :: [String]
  , ys :: [Bool]
  }
```

```
data T2
  { f :: OpaqueFunction X Y
  , xs :: [String]
  , ys :: [Bool]
  }
  deriving (Show)

newtype OpaqueFunction a b = OpaqueFunction (a -> b)

instance Show (OpaqueFunction a b) where
  show = const "<function>"
```

If you don’t want to do that, you can instead make the function a type parameter, and substitute it out when `Show`ing the type:

```
data T3' a
  { f :: a
  , xs :: [String]
  , ys :: [Bool]
  }
  deriving (Functor, Show)

newtype T3 = T3 (T3' (X -> Y))

data Opaque = Opaque

instance Show Opaque where
  show = const "..."

instance Show T3 where
  show (T3 t) = show (Opaque <$ t)
```

Or I’ll refactor my data type to derive `Show` only for the parts I want to be `Show`able by default, and override the other parts:

```
data T4 = T4
  { f :: X -> Y
  , xys :: T4'     -- Move the other fields into another type.
  }

instance Show T4 where
  show (T4 f xys) = "T4 <function> " <> show xys

data T4' = T4'
  { xs :: [String]
  , ys :: [Bool]
  }
  deriving (Show)  -- Derive ‘Show’ for the showable fields.
```

Or if my type is small, I’ll use a `newtype` instead of `data`, and derive `Show` via something like `OpaqueFunction`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}

newtype T5 = T5 (X -> Y, [String], [Bool])
  deriving (Show) via (OpaqueFunction X Y, [String], [Bool])
```

You can use the [`iso-deriving`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iso-deriving) package to do this for `data` types using lenses if you care about keeping the field names / record accessors.

As for `Eq` (or `Ord`), it’s not a good idea to have an instance that equates values that can be observably distinguished in some way, since some code will treat them as identical and other code will not, and now you’re forced to care about *stability*: in some circumstance where I have `a == b`, should I pick `a` or `b`? This is why *substitutability* is a law for `Eq`: `forall x y f. (x == y) ==> (f x == f y)` if `f` is a “public” function that upholds the invariants of the type of `x` and `y` (although floating-point also violates this). A better choice is something like `T4` above, having equality only for the parts of a type that can satisfy the laws, or explicitly using comparison modulo some function at use sites, e.g., `comparing someField`.

Comment: This is pretty cool, especially `T5`. Is it possible to use this on ADTs that don't use GADT extensions? I guess T5 isn't polymorphic? (which is what I want tbh)

Comment: @cheater: Yeah, if I understand you correctly, you can use `DerivingVia` on polymorphic types, and even many GADTs with `StandaloneDeriving`. The `via` deriving strategy just requires `Coercible` instances, which are automatically derived for `newtype`s that are representationally equal. There are some deficiencies in the “role” system that enables coercions, where the compiler can’t prove a coercion safe, so you may sometimes need to tweak your types, or use `QuantifiedConstraints` to talk about higher-order types, e.g. `forall a b. Coercible a b => Coercible (f a) (f b)`.

Comment: I just realized I forgot that I need multiple constructors on this type. So it won't fit inside a `newtype`. How would you do something like `T5` for an ADT with two constructors, and no type parameters? Would you be kind enough to append your answer?

Comment: @cheater: If you want to use `DerivingVia` directly, you’d need to use something like `newtype X = X (Either Y Z) deriving (…) via (Either Y' Z')`, or `iso-deriving` with a `data` type. I’ll see about adding an example of the latter, at least. I hope that in the future we can derive more things structurally for `data` types. At the moment you’d have to build a decent amount of the machinery yourself through `Generic`, with techniques like those described in [Mirror Mirror: Reflection and Encoding Via](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2020/02/04/mirror_mirror.html).

Comment: writing stuff for `data` sounds really painful - I think your `newtype ... Either` suggestion might be better for now. I do hope at least basic `data` types can be supported better in the near future.

Comment: I've accepted your answer right now for being by far the best, and I hope if `data` support materializes you'll update the answer :)

Comment: QuickCheck has a really general version of that newtype: `newtype Hide a = Hide a`. Then `instance Show (Hide a) where --something uninformative`. So `Hide (a -> b)` is a function with a `Show` instance. If the function isn't polymorphic, it might make more sense to use an instance that shows its type: `newtype ShowByType a = ShowByType a` with `instance Typeable a => Show (ShowByType a) where -- show the TypeRep in context`.

Answer (score 8):

One way you can get proper `Eq` and `Show` instances is to, instead of hard-coding that function field, make it a type parameter and provide a function that just “erases” that field. I.e., if you have

```
data Foo = Foo
  { fooI :: Int
  , fooF :: Int -> Int }
```

you change it to

```
data Foo' f = Foo
  { _fooI :: Int
  , _fooF :: f }
 deriving (Eq, Show)
type Foo = Foo' (Int -> Int)

eraseFn :: Foo -> Foo' ()
eraseFn foo = foo{ fooF = () }
```

Then, `Foo` will still not be `Eq`- or `Show`able (which after all it *shouldn't* be), but to make a `Foo` value showable you can just wrap it in `eraseFn`.

Comment: This is interesting. I guess once you have a value with a function inside you can just do myVal { _fooF = () } to get a printable version. The issue with this is that it implies Foo should be polymorphic in f, whereas it really shouldn't be, it should only accept one type there.

Comment: Well, it doesn't need to be “publicly polymorphic” – you can export only the type `Foo` but not `Foo'`, then it looks as if the function field is hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

The module `Text.Show.Functions` in `base` provides a show instance for functions that displays `<function>`.  To use it, just:

```
import Text.Show.Functions
```

It just defines an instance something like:

```
instance Show (a -> b) where
  show _ = "<function>"
```

Similarly, you can define your own `Eq` instance:

```
import Text.Show.Functions

instance Eq (a -> b) where
  -- all functions are equal...
  -- ...though some are more equal than others
  _ == _ = True

data Foo = Foo Int Double (Int -> Int) deriving (Show, Eq)

main = do
  print $ Foo 1 2.0 (+1)
  print $ Foo 1 2.0 (+1) == Foo 1 2.0 (+2)  -- is True
```

This will be an orphan instance, so you'll get a warning with `-Wall`.

Obviously, these instances will apply to all functions.  You can write instances for a more specialized function type (e.g., only for `Int -> String`, if that's the type of the function field in your data type), but there is no way to simultaneously (1) use the built-in `Eq` and `Show` deriving mechanisms to derive instances for your datatype, (2) not introduce a `newtype` wrapper for the function field (or some other type polymorphism as mentioned in the other answers), and (3) only have the function instances apply to the function field of your data type and not other function values of the same type.

If you really want to limit applicability of the custom function instances without a `newtype` wrapper, you'd probably need to build your own generics-based solution, which wouldn't make much sense unless you wanted to do this for a lot of data types.  If you go this route, then the `Generics.Deriving.Show` and `Generics.Deriving.Eq` modules in `generic-deriving` provide templates for these instances which could be modified to treat functions specially, allowing you to derive per-datatype instances using some stub instances something like:

```
instance Show Foo where showsPrec = myGenericShowsPrec
instance Eq Foo where (==) = myGenericEquality
```

Comment: The problem with “optional instance” modules is that they're viral, anyone downstream will then also have the questionable blessing of that instance being in scope. (Yay, communism... the pigs would rejoice.)

Comment: this is actually a pretty good trick for when I'll want to debug something, I'll just add "deriving Show" to the right type and add the import up top. Great stuff! Not sure about the virality argument, but when debugging like this there's no need to keep this code around.

Comment: If I had my way, GHC.Show would declare `class Show a where type HahaNoOverlap a; type HahaNoOverlap = (); ....` and `instance Unsatisfiable "You can't show functions!" => Show (a -> b) where showsPrec = exfalso`. But I'm a very strict kind of guy.

Answer (score 2):

I proposed an idea for adding annotations to fields [`via` fields](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/pbq9rn/via_fields_finer_granularity_in_deriving/), that allows operating on behaviour of individual fields.

```
data A = A
  { a :: Int
  , b :: Int
  , c :: Int -> Int via Ignore (Int->Int)
  }
  deriving
    stock GHC.Generic

  deriving (Eq, Show)
    via Generically A   -- assuming Eq (Generically A)
                        --        Show (Generically A)
```

But this is already possible with the ["microsurgery" library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-data-0.9.2.0/docs/Generic-Data-Microsurgery.html), but you might have to write some boilerplate to get it going. Another solution is to write separate behaviour in ["sums-of-products style"](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/gn8c5r/derivingvia_sumsofproducts/)

```
data A = A Int Int (Int->Int)
  deriving
    stock GHC.Generic

  deriving
    anyclass SOP.Generic

  deriving (Eq, Show)
    via A <--> '[ '[ Int, Int, Ignore (Int->Int) ] ]
```